# Why did GitHub decide my (100% C) repository was 50% C++?

Tags: github, github-linguist

I have a GitHub [repository](https://github.com/aaronryank/libportable) that is C-only. After my [latest commit](https://github.com/aaronryank/libportable/commit/644ee968d1af5fe2da281b8dfdce6e6ad3cd4504), in which I modified preprocessor spacing in a header file, GitHub decided my repository was 50.2% C++. I clicked on the link to look at the [C++ code](https://github.com/aaronryank/libportable/search?l=C%2B%2B) and it showed my header file [`portable.h`](https://github.com/aaronryank/libportable/blob/644ee968d1af5fe2da281b8dfdce6e6ad3cd4504/portable.h).

Why does GitHub think my repo is 50% C++? And more importantly, *how can I change its mind?*

Comment: This seems quite **offtopic** to me

Comment: `portable.h` is listed in c++. anyway should be closed....

Comment: @Yvon Huh, it shows up now.

Comment: maybe it can be fixed at the github side?

Comment: @IMSoP Are you fluent in C? `# define` is common preprocessor spacing.

Comment: @IMSoP: I checked. `# define` is valid C.

Comment: This question isn't about programming, but about the inner working of a third party service which only the provider of said service knows the answer about.

Comment: @Braiam Nope, [linguist is open-source](https://github.com/github/linguist).

Comment: See: [is this question off-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/345264/is-this-github-linguist-question-off-topic) on Meta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out how to fix it. I added a [linguist override](https://github.com/github/linguist#overrides) line to my `.gitattributes` file:

```
*.h linguist-language=C
```

I'm still not sure why GitHub decided the file was C++. If an answer is posted which solves that question, I'll accept it.

Comment: probably because you wrote c++ in comment?

Comment: @Yvon a) how would that cause it to decide the file was C++? b) where?

Comment: Line 229 that's what I mean

Answer (score -4):

It might be related to the fact that C++ is a superset of C, it means any C project is also a C++ project.

Comment: My other repos: [all C](https://github.com/aaronryank/c-prohackr112), [all C](https://github.com/aaronryank/finer-points-of-c), [all C](https://github.com/aaronryank/rk-lang), [all C](https://github.com/aaronryank/minproj), [all C](https://github.com/aaronryank/arkdoc). Nope.